# I want to know why isn't sending data to the MySQL?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to send data to the database.My PHP Files are OK,because I had tested that with postman and it send data to the database.But when I used Android app for that it shouldn't send data to the database.Here is my java method for the sending data.Reply me with the solution please.

```
 public void insertData(String name,String category,int quantity){
        String url = "http://192.168.172.2/foods/insert.php";
    try {
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("category", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(category, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("quantity", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(quantity), "UTF-8");


        URL url1 = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(data);
        writer.flush();

        Log.d("datainsert","success"+data);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.d("datainsert","Error"+e.getMessage());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("datainsert","Error"+e.getMessage());
   }

<?PHP
require "config.php";

global $connect;

if (isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_POST['category']) and isset($_POST['quantity'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$intq = (int)$quantity;


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST") {

$query = "INSERT INTO food_details(food_name,category,quantity) VALUES('$name','$category',$intq);";

  if($q = mysqli_query($connect,$query)){
    echo "successfully inserted";
  }else{
  //echo  mysqli_error(mysqli_query($connect,$query));
    echo "not success";
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $connect->error;
  }
}
}

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the PHP code as it may help understand how it is expecting to receive the data.

Comment: your are using POST method but passing parameter for GET. use Map or HasMap to post parameters.

Comment: @NigelRen here is my php file used for inserting.But I can't see any.

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari I think POST Method also can used for the inserting data.So as I used post method there is no need to pass the parameters along with url.If can show me how can I get done.I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending Data to server using POST method `Uri.Builder` class for creating query String.As follows

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
        .appendQueryParameter("firstParam", paramValue1)
        .appendQueryParameter("secondParam", paramValue2)
String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
```

For your question specific your post method will be as follows

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.172.2/foods/insert.php");
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);     //change according to need 
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);  //change according to need 
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                .appendQueryParameter("name", name)
                .appendQueryParameter("category", category)
                .appendQueryParameter("quantity", quantity);
        String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(query);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        conn.connect();

        //get response from server
        String response = conn.getResponseMessage();
        Log.d("URl->", response);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I hope its work  for you

Comment: thanks for ur help.But it isn't worked either.nothing showing on database or logcat showing errors

Comment: php file working.Because it work with postman and get parameters from postman and insert to the database.It should on the android part.But I can't find any error on the logcat

Comment: @Sandaruwan Bamunusinghe I have updated answer. now u can check response in logcat

Comment: It worked.The fact is the inserting to the db did when only if I defined the response from server part and neither it won't enter data to the db.By the way thanks friend finally worked.